# MySQL ERROR: Not Connected

Tags: mysql

I am learning MySQL and stumbled upon a problem after installation of MySQL. I switched to sql mode and from there I tried to connect to root@localhost but after I inputted the password, it says there is no such Host. I tried other host names, but the same results show where it says

> ERROR: 2005: No such host is known 'hostname'

I even tried to make a simple table, but when I enter it, I get the error that says ERROR: Not Connected, which was expected. How exactly do I get through this, I am a bit lost despite having everything installed.

I use commands such as:

> mysql-sql> \connect 127.0.01;

From there enter a password and no success.

Comment: Can you post the command you are using and the error message as well?

Comment: I post the commands and the errors I get..

Answer (score 2):

Check the list of hosts names inside this file
**C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts**
If you can't see this **127.0.0.1 localhost** add it on new line on bottom.
If it's there but the line start with **#** remove this symbol.

Comment: I am trying to save that document because there was a # symbol and I removed it, but it tells me that I don't have permission to save in the location and that I should contact the administrator for permission. I am the admin, which is odd.

Comment: Run your editor program (notepad etc.) as administrator first, then open the file and edit it.

Comment: I made that tweak as the admin, I still get the same error message saying that there is no such host found.

Answer (score 0):

You can try "127.0.01" instead localhost.

Comment: I tried doing that, but when I inputted it, it said: ERROR: 2005: No such host is known '127.0.01;"

Answer (score 0):

I think, Felipe meant ***\connect root@127.0.0.1*** instead of 127.0.01